# Maven is creating a war using the wrong classes directory, or it is putting the compiled classes in the wrong place

Tags: java, maven, war

```
MyProject > src
          > target
                   > MyProject   > classes (1)
                   > classes (2)
```

The actual newly compiled code is being put into 2, however the war file is getting created using 1. Thus my war file is not up to date at all.

What should I be doing ? Shown below snippet of my pom ... :

```
<build>
        <finalName>MyProject</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    <warName>MyProject</warName>

                </configuration>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Can you attach some example pom.xml to show us the wrong behavior?

Comment: @Nightsorrow which bit of it do you want see ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

target/PROJ is nothing but exploded war.

try deleting target directory. Perform maven build from commandline. and check if all things are created as they are at this point. If so, then maven is behaving correctly as both of the places contains updated class files and that target/PROJ directory is exploded war directory. You can use path to that directory to setup a context in tomcat/web container.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit in doubt on what you are showing.

Normally in war project, the target should be something like

```
PROJ
  + target
    + classes
    + PROJ-version
      + WEB-INF
        + classes
```

I have never see a `target/PROJ` in Maven WAR project

If what I am showing is what you seen, then it is what Maven always do.

Source are compiled and put in classes.

During creation of WAR, different files, including the project's `target/classes`, will be copied to `PROJ-version` directory which form the structure of WAR, and it will be used to create the WAR file.

Therefore there should be no problem that Maven is using `target/PROJ-version/WEB-INF/classes` in creating the WAR, as it is getting copied from `target/classes` when you are building.

If it is not your case, probably I will suggest you share your POM.  The directory you mentioned doesn't seems reasonable for a WAR project.